Function returning NULL value for string despite, Print function before returning prints a legitimate string in C
here is my function. It is supposed to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings. (A Leetcode question, if you can recall)
printf("Final value being returned %s\n", s); prints a legitimate string. And in fact the correct string for the values being passed to the function.
For some reason that same array when I'm trying to return, it returns null.
Thank you for your help.
char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {
    char s[200];
    for (int j=0; j<200; j++){
        if (strs[0][j] != '\0'){
            printf("hello\n");
            s[j]=strs[0][j];
            printf("%s\n", s);
        }
        for (int i=1; i<strsSize; i++){
            if (strs[i][j] == '\0')
                return s;
            if (strs[i][j] != s[j]){
                s[j]='\0';
                printf("Final value being returned %s\n", s);
                return s;
            }

        }
    }
    return s;
}


You must not return s; – the pointer target will no longer exist.

Aside, make sure you only output exactly what you are asked to: no more and no less.

@WeatherVane LeetCode doesn't have any requirements for output to stdout; it only checks the return value.
